# SHELL: GIT branch to variable

Tags: git, shell

I need some help. How can i get the value of **git branch** to be in a variable to check for if and else condition.

```
 COMMIT_MESSAGE="Update"
 BRANCH_PUSH="master"
 git branch
 if [git branch == $BRANCH_PUSH]; then
    echo "Success"
 else   
     echo "Error"
 fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do it:

```
git_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
if [[ "$git_branch" == "$BRANCH_PUSH" ]]; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "error"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the git branch you can do it a few ways but this is one way:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | cut -d"/" -f 3
```

Lovely one liner :)

so:

```
COMMIT_MESSAGE="Update"
BRANCH_PUSH="master"
git-branch = "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | cut -d"/" -f 3)"
if [$git-branch == "$BRANCH_PUSH"]; then
    echo "Success"
else   
    echo "Error"
fi
```